# How do you get/extract the result set from a VBA web form query

Tags: vba, excel

I using the following VBA to submit a web form. The query works great, but I don't know how to capture the result of the query.  I am running the query from Excel so it would be nice to display the result in a message msgbox("Dispay Result") or Cell.  I tried using the IE object (IE.text, IE.value), but had not luck.

```
Dim IE As Object

Sub GetOFAC()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://sanctionssearch.ofac.treas.gov/"

    Application.StatusBar = "Submitting"
    ' Wait while IE loading...
    While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
    ' **********************************************************************
    delay 5
    IE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_txtLastName").Value = "Apple"
    delay 5
    IE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_btnSearch").Click
    '**********************************************************************
    Application.StatusBar = "Form Submitted"
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
```

Comment: What have you tried for capturing the result? It looks like the results are returned in table `gvSearchResults`. Are you getting the `.innerText` of that anywhere?

Comment: @Tim I had tried this: MsgBox (gvSearchResults.innerText)  But I get an error message stating the object does not support this property or method.

Comment: Try iterating the tr then the td tagnames. You should be able to get the innertext of each of the Td's.

Comment: @RyanWildry  I'm a little out of my depth.  How would one iterate the tr and td.  I'm assuming you mean table row and table data, yes?

Comment: Yes. Select the Table element with the ID of the table. Then Select all tr with getElementsByTagName("tr"), then iterate all TD's as part of the innerloop with getElementsByTagName("td")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment. It appears that you aren't trying to grab the results anywhere. The results are listed in a table with the id `gvSearchResults`. You can use the `.GetElementsbyID` method to select this table element from the DOM, then you can use the `.InnerText` property to see what text is in this element.

```
Dim IE As Object

Sub GetOFAC()
    Dim strResults as String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://sanctionssearch.ofac.treas.gov/"

    Application.StatusBar = "Submitting"
    ' Wait while IE loading...
    While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
    ' **********************************************************************
    delay 5
    IE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_txtLastName").Value = "Apple"
    delay 5
    IE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_btnSearch").Click
    '**********************************************************************
    Application.StatusBar = "Form Submitted"

    ' Wait while the results load
    While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    'The results have loaded so select the table and get the text
    strResults = IE.Document.getElementById("gvSearchResults").InnerText
    MsgBox strResults

    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
```

I haven't tested this, but it should give you a little better idea of how to interact with IE and the DOM (Document Object Model).